# How to count distinct query in Rails 4 with Postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1

I have this ActiveRecord query:

```
Stock.select('DISTINCT ON (stocks.part_number)*').joins(:part, :manufacturer)
.includes(:manufacturer, :part).order(:part_number).with_cat(category).
where(manufacturers: {abbr: ['manufacturer1', 'manufacturer2']})
```

`with_cat` is a scope:

```
scope :with_cat, -> (category) { where(parts: {category_id: category}) }
```

Now the reason I am using `Distinct on` is because every manufacturer can have the same part as another, hence duplicates. I do not want duplicates. The above gets the job done. Except when I add `count` to it I get an error.

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON (stocks.part_number)*) FROM "stocks...
                              ^
: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON (stocks.part_number)*) FROM "stocks" 
INNER JOIN "parts" ON "parts"."id" = "stocks"."part_id" 
INNER JOIN "manufacturers" ON "manufacturers"."id" = "stocks"."manufacturer_id" 
WHERE "parts"."category_id" = 17 AND "manufacturers"."abbr" IN ('manufacturer1', 'manufacturer2')
```

Not really sure how to add a count to the query without causing that error. I'm not familiar with `Distinct on` either. Any explanation as to why this is happening would be great!

Comment: Can you also show the SQL query that's generated when you're *not* using `count`?

Comment: @jeffdill2 its the same as the result query with count, but minus the `count` and its enclosing parens. I can add it, but its just a few characters to remove and im not in front of my comp at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it fix the query if you use the count ahead of `distinct`? Got the idea per [this postgres documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAONnt+72Mtg6kyAFDTHXFWyPPY-QRbAtuREak+64Lm1KN1c-wg@mail.gmail.com)

```
Stock.select('count(distinct part_number)')...
```

Comment: I tried using normal distinct and it didn't work. But I might have been doing something wrong. I'll give it another shot. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Turns out the issue I was having was not related to the query, but I thought it was. Your answer worked. Thanks!